# Eclipse giving java.lang.AbstractMethodError for DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, saxparser, javax.xml

I am trying to run junit for a maven project but I am not able to proceed as I am  getting the error

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

It seems as eclipse is unable to find the implementation of the above method.
My eclipse is configured with `jdk 1.8.0_144`.
But if I compile the project from command line using the command mvn clean install its a success. I only get this error while running it in eclipse.

Comment: @Jayant Nayak, Did u find solution for your problem? Even I am also facing same problem.

Comment: @Javadroider I wasn't able to exactly solve it. But  you can try to set the correct jdk path in your eclipse instead of the jre and check if it solves the issue.